# How macro works?

Tags: c

I was expecting x to be doubled. But surprisingly output is other.Why this is happening?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define abs(x) ( x<0 ? -x : x )
int x;
int doubleGlobalX()
{
   x*=2;
   return x;
}

 int main(void)
 {
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("%d\n",abs(doubleGlobalX()));
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
abs(doubleGlobalX())
```

This becomes, literally

```
doubleGlobalX()<0 ? -doubleGlobalX() : doubleGlobalX()
```

Do you see the issue now? `x` literally becomes whatever is passed to the macro. This means you're calling your function multiple times: once in the condition to the ternary, and then once in either of the branches; depending on what the condition was.

The simple solution is to just not use a macro here. The gains from using a macro will be extraordinarily minimal, if there's any gains at all. Change it to a normal function and it will behave as you expect since `doubleGlobalX()` will then run once, before `abs` is called.

Answer (score 3):

A macro results in text replacement.  Your use of `abs(doubleGlobalX())` will be replaced by

```
(doubleGlobalX()<0 ? -doubleGlobalX() : doubleGlobalX() )
```

which will result in `doubleGlobalX` being called twice.